# Problems changing the default configuration of JBoss Mail service

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, jboss

Right now i have to make migration of one application.

**Basic configuration:**

1. JBOSS 5.1.0 GA
2. Seam 2.2.0.GA
3. JBPM 3.2.2
4. RichFaces 3.3.1.GA
5. Hibernate 3.3.1.GA
6. OS: Debian/Linux

Application has been deployed on JBoss server with its own configuration.
On old machine there was postfix (localhost, port 25) for sending messages.

On new machine i have different host and port.

What i have now in *components.xml*:

```
<mail:mail-session session-jndi-name="java:/Mail" />
```

My *mail-service.xml*:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.mail.MailService"
     name="jboss:service=Mail">
<attribute name="JNDIName">java:/Mail</attribute>
<attribute name="User">XXX</attribute>
<attribute name="Password">XXX</attribute>
<attribute name="Configuration">
  <!-- A test configuration -->
  <configuration>
    <!-- Change to your mail server prototocol -->
    <property name="mail.store.protocol" value="pop3"/>
    <property name="mail.transport.protocol" value="smtp"/>

    <!-- Change to the user who will receive mail  -->
    <property name="mail.user" value="XXX"/>

    <!-- Change to the mail server  -->
    <property name="mail.pop3.host" value="localhost"/>

    <!-- Change to the SMTP gateway server -->
    <property name="mail.smtp.host" value="XXX"/>
    <property name="mail.smtp.auth" value="true"></property>
    <property name="mail.smtp.ssl.enable" value="false"></property>
    <property name="mail.smtp.port" value="587"/>

    <property name="mail.smtp.connectiontimeout" value="20000"></property>
    <property name="mail.smtp.timeout" value="20000"></property>


    <!-- The mail server port -->

    <!-- Change to the address mail will be from  -->
    <property name="mail.from" value="XXX"/>

    <!-- Enable debugging output from the javamail classes -->
    <property name="mail.debug" value="true"/>
  </configuration>
</attribute>
<depends>jboss:service=Naming</depends>
```

I'm intrested only in sending messages.

But still:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;


nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    <xxx>
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 59 more
```

Of course connection is refused because application is still pointed on localhost:25. 
I have tried to find with grep other configurations, allocations, etc. mail-service is started (jmx-console info). Still its looked like aplication is not configured properly but using defaults.. Whats wrong?

PS: I'm not specialist in JBoss. I don't have root account on this hosting server.

Comment: did you change "localhost" in mail-service.xml hidden behind the XXX parm here `<property name="mail.smtp.host" value="XXX"/>` ? if so , did you restart jBoss after that ? if so did you clean the cache of the jBoss too ?

Comment: Yes for all. There is my host value, Few times i have delete all tmp folder content working with that.

Comment: may be the access to the SMTP server is hardcoded - the developper knew there was a smtp on "localhost" and put that whitout using the service mail :/ If you could ask arround you or have a look at the source code to check. On my side I'm trying to find if another mail service is setup somewhere else.

Comment: To be sure : the host you put in place of XXX ; is of course not the hostname where jboss is running ? ; just to be sure ;)

Comment: Nobody to ask unfortunately. I thought also that it is hardcoded, but I tried to use grep on all sources to find files with words "localhost", regexs like "localhost.*25" etc. There was hardcoded in components.xml: <mail:mail-session localhost="localhost" port="25"/> so i changed it like above. Also i tried to change in <mail:mail-session /> for new host and port- no effect ;/

Comment: It's lookback host so answer is not that simple ;) Local mail server don't work on localhost but on public IP address. It should not be a problem. In addition, the port does not match...

Comment: and what about a `grep -ri mail.smtp.host *` ?

Comment: so the SMTP and JBOSS are on the same server ?

Comment: Nothing in sources, in server folder only mail-service.xml. Running configuration has my value, other smtp.nosuchhost.nosuchdomain.com but I don't use them.

Comment: so the SMTP and JBOSS are on the same server ? - yes

Comment: I think you should setup the SMTP to be able to send mail from localhost too. I have no more idea why jboss is stuck to handle mails if all is correct inside mail-service.xml, by correct i mean being able to reach the SMTP server with a `telnet myhost 25` with the parameter you put in the mail-service.xml file.

Comment: I think its not a problem. IMHO application don't use this mail-service.xml at all. There is still different port 567 not 25. Unfortunately i can't change SMTP server configurations.